# Track Eclipse Java-Compiler settings in Git for projects

Tags: java, eclipse, git

In our project we aim to use the strictest possible settings for warnings/errors in Eclipse.

The question is simple: How do we track these settings in our git repo such that importing the project (or simply doing an update) in Eclipse will load these compiler settings and apply them?

Comment: Shouldn't be tracking Eclipse things.  Those belong in Maven pom.xml.  That you can track.  Your CI process had better not be relying on Eclipse.

Comment: Interesting point, thank you

Comment: Don't. Not all are using Eclipse IDE, not all are using the same version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody created a maven plugin for this that may work: https://github.com/topicusonderwijs/m2e-settings

I have no experience using this plugin; so I can't vouch for it.

The next best thing is simply exporting your settings and putting the file in your git repository with some instructions for developers to please import this.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the project's preferences for the Java Compiler Errors and Warnings to be project-specific, they will be stored in the project itself under its .settings folder and used when pulled by everyone else during development. However you choose to build the final version, CI or not, is your own business.